# Can't get IViewObject::Draw To Work

Tags: windows, winapi, com

I need to implement a screen capturing service (C++), that fires up ie navigates to a site and then takes a grab of the site.

I loaded the site and have received the DISPID_FRAMENAVIGATECOMPLETE event and i'm at the stage where i'm calling IViewObject::Draw like this:

```
SHANDLE_PTR hwnd = 0;
browser->get_HWND(&hwnd);

RECT rc ={0,0,100, 100};
BOOL tst = GetClientRect((HWND)hwnd, &rc);

HDC hDC = GetDC((HWND)hwnd);
HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rc.right - rc.left, 
                                         rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);

//hr = OleDraw(ivo, DVASPECT_DOCPRINT, hdc, &rc);
hr = ivo->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, NULL, NULL, hDC, 
               hDCMem, (LPCRECTL)&rc, NULL, NULL, 0);

//copy to clipboard
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
CloseClipboard();
```

Everything is returning the correct return values, S_OK etc;

But all I ever get on the clipboard is a black rect - when copied into paint, which is presumable the plain bitmap data created via CreatCompatibleBitmap.

If I use PrintWindow instead of IViewObject::Draw then it works, how ever I can't use that as it doesn't work with windows that are not visible (although at the moment in my testing everything is visible).

Anyone any ideas whats wrong with the code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

stupidly, I was forgetting some COM basics. The call is across process boundaries. Once I hosted the control (just hacked about an MFC app that used CHTMLView) it works as it should.

However, I think I should have had some kind of error telling this.